# For what controls should I use md-input-container

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

What are the controls that I can put inside a "md-input-container" with angular material design?

The reason why I ask this is because of this sample for example:

```
<md-input-container>
   <input flex="" flex min="0" max="20" type="number" ng-model="testNumber">
</md-input-container>
```

Why I look at the "Spinner" aka slider samples:

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/slider

Nowhere is the md-input-container used. But only when I wrap a input of type number with a md-input-container the look of the spinner seems right as a material component.

Looking at the API of the md-input-container: 
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdInputContainer

They mention only "Input" and "TextArea"

Well Input can be of any type...

When I look now back again to the spinner/slider samples all of them do NOT use a md-input-container.

So something is wrong or undocumented here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`md-input-container` has to be a parent container for any type of input (text, number, date, etc) in order to get that material look and feel.

However, if you do not need these material-styled placeholders, labels and validation, you can still use input which is not nested in the container. That was the case in the Sliders example.

Answer (score 0):

`md-input-container` supports only:

- `input`
- `textarea`

Only 1 input can be in each `md-input-container` or an exception will be thrown.

The md-slider demos and docs have all been updated to use `md-input-container`.

Many [input types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Browser_compatibility) like `email`, `week`, `number`, `month`, `password`, `search`, `tel`, `text`, and `time` are supported by `md-input-container`.

The following types may not have ideal behavior:

- `checkbox` - `md-checkbox` preferred
- `image` - `ng-click` on `img` preferred
- `radio` - `md-radio-button` in a `md-radio-group` preferred
- `file` - placeholder alignment is off in Chrome
- `submit` - `md-button` preferred
- `reset` - `md-button` preferred
- `range` - `md-slider` preferred

Please make sure to use the `angular-aria` module if you are using inputs in your project. It will automatically make your app more accessible and compliant to standards related to accessibility.